# Redis for silverstripe 4 caching

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am using SilverStripe 4.2.2.

Wondering how could I configure Redis for caching in SilverStripe 4?

Comment: Seems it doesn't work out of the box yet, you'll need an adapter to connect Redis to SS4. See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/performance/caching/#adapters

Comment: Further to the above, you could configure the [symfony/cache Redis adapter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/redis_adapter.html). Note that this would only work for caching that uses the symfony/cache API, but not template caches for example

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [pstaender/silverstripe-redis-cache](https://packagist.org/packages/pstaender/silverstripe-redis-cache) which should make it a lot easier to get started with SilverStripe 4 and Redis right off the bat (since it implements `CacheFactory` and offers some configuration for SilverStripe). Also nice that it also uses [predis](https://packagist.org/packages/predis/predis), similar to Symfony's cache component noted above.

This happens to be ideal for me as well since one of my *primary* reasons for using Redis would be for template caching distributed across a cluster.